# Elemento posicionado com position absolute está expandindo para cima

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma `nav` e dentro dela possuo um ícone de notificações.

Eu fiz um `*ngIf` para mostrar um *card* quando o usuário clicar no ícone, posicionei esse *card* com position absolute, porém dentro do card eu possuo vários conteúdos que deve aparecer em demanda conforme o cliente clica no tópico, porém quando uso position absolute, meu card é expandido pra cima sempre que aparece um novo elemento, gostaria que ele mantesse sua posição.

Segue gif mostrando o problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu possuir muitos elementos abertos acredito que o botão de fechar e o card ficará escondido. Como posso resolver isso?

Segue meu html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light fixed-top blue lighten-4">

    <div (click)="abreMenu()" id="nav-icon4">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>

    <div id="colunaTituloPagina">
        <h2 class="tipografiaDash">{{nomePagina}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="divSino">
        <i id="iconeSino" matBadge="22" matBadgeColor="warn" class="fa fa-bell animated swing infinite"></i>
    </div>

    <div id="cardNotificacao" class="card">
        <div class="conteudoNotificacao">
            <div id="headerNotificacao">
                <h6 class="descricaoNotificacoes">Notificações</h6>
                <i id="iconeFechaNotificacao" class="fa fa-close"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <h6 (click)="mostraPedidos = !mostraPedidos">Pedidos</h6>

                <h6 class="animated fadeIn" *ngIf="mostraPedidos">Lorem ipsum blalalblab</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Meu css:

```
 #iconeFechaNotificacao{
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #da1717;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px;
 }

 #headerNotificacao{
     display: inline-flex;
 }

 #cardNotificacao{
    min-width: 320px;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 30px;
 }
```

Eu utilizo o [Material Design Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou a propriedade `top`, que você pode usar o valor que achar melhor na distância do topo da página (ex. `top: 10px;`):

> Coloquei um botão para retirar o `top` para ver o efeito.

```js
function topo(){
   $("#cardNotificacao").css("top", "auto");
}
```

```css
#iconeFechaNotificacao{
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #da1717;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px;
 }

 #headerNotificacao{
     display: inline-flex;
 }

 #cardNotificacao{
    min-width: 320px;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    top: 0; /* distância do topo */
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light fixed-top blue lighten-4">

    <div (click)="abreMenu()" id="nav-icon4">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>

    <div id="colunaTituloPagina">
        <h2 class="tipografiaDash">{{nomePagina}}</h2>
        <button style="left: -100px; position: relative;" onclick="topo()">Retirar o top</button>
    </div>

    <div id="divSino">
        <i id="iconeSino" matBadge="22" matBadgeColor="warn" class="fa fa-bell animated swing infinite"></i>
    </div>

    <div id="cardNotificacao" class="card">
        <div class="conteudoNotificacao">
            <div id="headerNotificacao">
                <h6 class="descricaoNotificacoes">Notificações</h6>
                <i id="iconeFechaNotificacao" class="fa fa-close"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <h6 (click)="mostraPedidos = !mostraPedidos">Pedidos</h6>

                <h6 class="animated fadeIn" *ngIf="mostraPedidos">Lorem ipsum blalalblab<br><br><br><br><br></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</nav>
```